# What's the correct terraform syntax to allow an external AWS role to subscribe and read from AWS SNS topic?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam, amazon-sns, terraform-provider-aws

I want to create a policy so a specific aws role (not in the same account) let's say *arn:aws:iam::123123123123:role/sns-read-role* can subscribe and receive messages from my SNS topic in AWS.

From the [official terraform docs about aws_sns_topic_policy](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/sns_topic_policy) example it would be

```
resource "aws_sns_topic" "test" {
  name = "my-topic-with-policy"
}

resource "aws_sns_topic_policy" "default" {
  arn = aws_sns_topic.test.arn
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.sns_topic_policy.json
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "sns_topic_policy" {

  statement {
    actions = [
      "SNS:Subscribe",
      "SNS:Receive"
    ]

    condition {
      test     = "StringEquals"
      variable = "AWS:SourceOwner"
      values = [
        123123123123
      ]
    }

    effect = "Allow"

    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = ["*"]
    }

    resources = [
      aws_sns_topic.test.arn
    ]
  }
}
```

But this would translate to *arn:aws:iam::123123123123:root* and filter only on *account-id*.

From [AWS JSON policy elements: Principal](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_principal.html) I understand the AWS syntax is

`"Principal": { "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::AWS-account-ID:role/role-name" }`

Adding the role in the condition like this

```
condition {
    test     = "StringEquals"
    variable = "AWS:SourceOwner"

    values = [
        arn:aws:iam::123123123123:role/sns-read-role
    ]
}
```

does not work.

It would make sense to add the role to the principal like this

```
principals {
    type        = "AWS"
    identifiers = ["arn:aws:iam::123123123123:role/sns-read-role"]
}
```

When I try to subscribe, I get an AuthorizationError: "Couldn't subscribe to topic..."

Do I need the condition together with the principal? Why even bother with the condition if you can use the principal in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

After some experimenting, I found that I don't need the condition. This works for me:

```
resource "aws_sns_topic" "test" {
  name = "my-topic-with-policy"
}

resource "aws_sns_topic_policy" "default" {
  arn = aws_sns_topic.test.arn
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.sns_topic_policy.json
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "sns_topic_policy" {

  statement {
    actions = [
      "SNS:Subscribe",
      "SNS:Receive"
    ]

    effect = "Allow"

    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = [
        "arn:aws:iam::123123123123:role/sns-read-role"
      ]
    }

    resources = [
      aws_sns_topic.test.arn
    ]
  }
}
```

In case you want to use parameters for your module:

```
principals {
    type = "AWS"
    identifiers = [
      "${var.account_arn}:role/${var.role}"
    ]
}
```